# (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)

Tags: python-3.x, django, excel, iis, pywin32

I am developing a Django (v 3.2.6) application (Python 3.9.1.) which needs to write into an Excel file using pywin32.com.

On the client side it works fine, but when I put in production using IIS (v 10) on a Windows 11 server, I get the error above.

I have a routine that reads in a file input by the user and writes to the project directory:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        # Create a form instance and populate it with the file from the request (binding):
        form = Name1_uploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create variable for uploaded file 
            uploaded_excel_file = form.cleaned_data['excel_file']
            # Write it to BASE_DIR
            with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, form.cleaned_data['excel_file'].name), 'wb+') as destination:

                for chunk in uploaded_excel_file.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
            # Allow the write process to conclude
            time.sleep(12)
            # Close the file
            destination.close()            
            # Call conversion function
            Name1_extraction(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, form.cleaned_data['excel_file'].name))
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index') )
        else:
            form = Name1_uploadForm()
```

This calls another function (below) that should open that same file:

```
def Name1_extraction(uploaded_excel_file):

    const = win32.constants

    # Need to run CoInitialize to use win32com.client
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    # Open Name1 excel with Win32com 
    excelFile = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

The complete error is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdE0P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4pcJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5IwE.png)

The error occurs when the following line of code is executed:

```
excelFile = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

The application pool is IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool.

DefaultAppPool has been granted full access to folders C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop and C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

With these actions I would not expect to see any errors

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Server side Office automation is not supported (Office COM interop in web apps on IIS), so don't waste anyone's time.

Comment: Thank you for your polite and constructive answer

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of Office, and Microsoft strongly recommends that developers look for alternatives to Automation of Office when they need to develop server-side solutions.

Due to limitations in the design of Office, changing the Office configuration alone is not sufficient to resolve all issues. Microsoft strongly recommends some alternatives that don't require a server-side installation of Office and can perform most common tasks more efficiently and faster than Automation.

Most server-side automation tasks involve document creation or editing. Office 2007 supports the new Open XML file format, which allows developers to create, edit, read, and transform file content on the server side. This is the recommended and supported method of handling changes to Office files from the service.

How to use the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office, please refer to the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Considerations for server-side Automation of Office, please refer to this Microsoft blog:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: thank you for the detailed information you provided. I have explored the SDK link but am unsure how to proceed. I require to edit Excel files through Python / Django setup on an IIS server. Is this SDK only to be used in Visual Studio with .NET?

Comment: At present, it seems that Microsoft's use of the OpenXML SDK is only based on the .net implementation method. You can refer to the link provided by Lex Li in the comment.

Comment: @295 There are several Python packages for reading / writing the Excel xml format eg `openpyxl`.

Comment: This is super not helpful. For example you receive a XLS file an need to convert it to the new XLSX format to work with it, but how are you supposed to do this?

Answer (score -2):

I've had a similar problem:
I had a Python program with the xlwings library and I created a .bat file.
When I launched it by hand it worked perfectly, but with Windows 10 Scheduler I received an error "(-2147024891, 'Access denied.', None, None)".

I carried out the automatic correction of the Excel file which can be done by going to Excel > File > Info > Verify document.

My problem was that the Windows Scheduler didn't accept comments in the .xlsm file.
I deleted all the comments and then the Windows Scheduler started